# Cannot move a value of dyn type

Tags: rust

I'm struggling really hard with this error, here is my code:

```
struct Dog {}
struct Cat {}

trait Animal {
    fn make_sound(self) -> String;
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn make_sound(self) -> String {
        String::from("woof")
    }
}

impl Animal for Cat {
    fn make_sound(self) -> String {
        String::from("meow")
    }
}

fn choose(vec: Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>, boo: bool) -> String {
    if boo {
        vec[0].make_sound()
    }
    else {
        vec[1].make_sound()
    }
}
```

Here is what the compiler says:

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type `dyn Animal`
  --> src/main.rs:22:9
   |
22 |         vec[0].make_sound()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the size of `dyn Animal` cannot be statically determined

error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type `dyn Animal`
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
25 |         vec[1].make_sound()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the size of `dyn Animal` cannot be statically determined

error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>`
  --> src/main.rs:22:9
   |
22 |         vec[0].make_sound()
   |         ^^^^^^^------------
   |         |      |
   |         |      value moved due to this method call
   |         move occurs because value has type `dyn Animal`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
note: `Animal::make_sound` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
  --> src/main.rs:5:19
   |
5  |     fn make_sound(self) -> String;
   |                   ^^^^

error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>`
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
25 |         vec[1].make_sound()
   |         ^^^^^^^------------
   |         |      |
   |         |      value moved due to this method call
   |         move occurs because value has type `dyn Animal`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I don't get why there are so many errors.

Comment: the `make_sound` function should take `&self` instead of `self` so that it doesn't need to consume the reference

Comment: To expand on that, `&self` means *borrow `self`* while `self` means *consume `self`*. This also applies to other arguments.

Comment: And if you need to own `self` you could also take `self: Box<Self>`, I think that should work too.

Comment: I've just tested it and `self: Box<Self>` does work when we need to move a `dyn`.

Answer (score 3):

When using [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html), you can only call methods that take some kind of pointer to `self`, such as the reference `&self`. Any other methods (ones with a bare `self` or `where Self: Sized`) are excluded from the trait object interface. Check out the section on [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety).

Your method works fine with a shared reference, so you can add that in to get this working. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=331acee5d07b16fc92b3323b1c7b7e16)

```rs
pub trait Animal {
    fn make_sound(&self) -> String;
}
```

## Why?

This limitation is for technical reasons. Trait objects have a virtual table that describes their trait methods. While these functions would be okay with taking `self`, the non-dynamic code that calls them needs to know at compile time how to give them the `self` argument.

When a method takes a reference `&self`, this is fine. `&self` compiles into a simple pointer, and `&dyn Animal` compiles into two pointers, one to the value and one to the vtable. So the conversion from `&dyn Animal` to `&self` just keeps the pointer to the value.

On the other hand, `self` can be any size. The size of a function's arguments determines how they're laid out in registers and on the stack, so there's no compile-time way for the correct arrangement to be set up in preparation for the virtual call.

This leaves one question: why not determine the layout at runtime? I haven't been able to find a definitive answer, but as far as I can tell, this is technically possible on an architecture level, but not implemented in any layer of the rust stack (rustc, llvm, linker), nor debug tools.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having trouble understanding how data is passed around in rust. While other answers are correct, I will try to explain it in the simplest way I can.

We all know that functions take arguments and use them to produce an output. There are several ways that function can handle these arguments:

1. Just look at the arguments, not modifying them, and produce output. This can be done using the `&` symbol. `fn foo(arg: &ArgType) -> OutType`. We say that the function `foo` borrows the `ArgType`. Real life example would be borrowing a notebook and using it in some way without modifying it in any way.
2. Modify the arguments and produce output. The syntax for that is `fn foo(arg: &mut ArgType) -> OutType`. We say that the function `foo` mutably borrows the `ArgType`. Real life example would be printing a document. You provide some text and a blank paper (mutable) and printer modifies it.

If you know some other languages, you should be familiar with first two points. Now comes the part where things are different.

3. The arguments are given to the function and it can do whatever it wants with them. The syntax is `fn foo(arg: ArgType) -> OutType`. We say that the `foo` takes ownership or consumes the argument, or the `arg` is moved to the function. In real life it would be like making a table out of wood. You get wood as input, you consume it to make a table. This is the most confusing part since other languages (like c++) make copies of data. In rust you have to be explicit when you want to make a copy.

Now to answer your question. The function `make_sound` consumes `self` to produce output. Now if we were to translate that to the real world example, it would be like an animal is transformed into a sound, never to be seen again. We also don't need to make a clone of an animal to transform it into a sound. We don't need to modify the animal in any way, therefore the simple borrow is the solution here. The correct signature would be `fn make_sound(&self) -> String`